# How can I wrap LSP errors?

Tags: neovim, lsp, neovim-qt

I have checked this post but the answer does not work for me. It is also quite old and archived.Basically I tried a big bunch of vim.lsp.util commands but none of them were recognized.

https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/gy8ko7/question_how_to_get_more_readable_error_messages/

I am using the official Neovim LSP plugin. I just want to wrap the errors and warning to new lines when they overflow because it currently does not happen. Maybe it's  a bug on my end.

Comment: Please [edit] to include more details. What is your LSP client? What do you mean by "wrap"? If you tried something from an external source, please include enough details directly in the question along with the link (to avoid link rot). What does "does not work" mean (error? no change? crash?)?

Comment: I have the impression that the api of the post is not existing anymore. At least the Neovim completion drive me to: `vim.lsp.diagnositc.get_line_diagnostics()`. Not a solution yet but an indication that we need more information about what you try to achieve. Would be good to have a simplified input (a simplified version of the script), the desired information, the tests you already did (even if they are not working :-) ).

Comment: Could you provide screenshot? Are you sure it is possible? Could you share screenshots or links that indicate that it is?

Comment: Only my intuition indicates that it must be possible. Also that Reddit post I think.

Comment: Ever found a solution?